# Difference between "available services" and "services available"

Tags: grammar, difference, phrase-usage

Both phrases are grammatically correct, but I would like to know when I should use one or the other. I couldn't find relevant information on the Internet.

For context, I am currently taking some notes about a command-line program in the form "action: command" and I don't know if I should write the action as "Show available services" or "Show services available". The same with "installed packages" and "packages installed".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct and natural, so either would be grammatically correct.

However, the versions with the adjective first are unambiguously noun phrases, as you intend, so this is the better choice.

The versions with the noun first could be sentences with a "be-verb" elided, like,  "Services *are* available" or "Packages *have been* installed" or the like, which is not your intent.